# BST Links and cases not working

Tags: c, binary-search-tree

I've a nested struct like this

```
typedef struct Node_link {
    struct Node_base *parent, *left, *right;
}Node_link;


typedef struct Node_base {
    struct Node_link link[2];
}Node_base;

typedef struct Node{
    struct Node_base base;
    int size;
    int *address;
}Node;


Node_base *head[2] ={NULL, NULL}; 
//head[0] stores int size and head[1] it's corresponding address
```

The node has right, left and parent link, all are nested e.g node->left->link.parent=node. I've to maintain all links(parent, left and right) and delete nodes.
I've tried a lot of cases and still missing some. Can someone tell me what all cases I need to use? Or refer me to some material? I searched a lot but no success.
My insert function is as follows:

```
Node_base *   insert(Node_base *location, Node_base *n) {
    if (head[0]==NULL)
    head[0]=n;
else
{
    if (location==NULL){
        location=n;
        return location;
    }
    else{

        if(((Node *)n)->size < ((Node *)location)->size){
            if(location->link[0].left==NULL)
            {
                location->link[0].left=n;
                location->link[0].left->link[0].parent=location;
            }
            else
                location->link[0].left=insert(location->link[0].left,n);
        return location;
    }
}
```

And I've the same nested insert function for head[1] which stores the size of node inserted in head[0].

Comment: Your structures seem all wrong to me. Shouldn't your insert function accept Node types? Why do you even need the separation between Node and Node_base? Why does Node_base need 2 Node_link structs? What part of this is given to you and what have you implemented yourself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to tell what's going on here.  Your code doesn't look remotely like any BST implementation I've ever seen.  Why the need for the Node_Link struct?  The pointers in the Node structs should define what the links are.  Why the parent pointer? That shouldn't be needed in a standard BST implementation.  All you should need is:

```
struct node {
    node *left;
    node *right;
    void *data;
    int size;
};

struct bst {
    node *root;
};
```